# Problems with Jboss 6.1+ deployment

Tags: jboss, jboss6.x

I think I have some related problems with JBOSS. If I start server with some project in the deploy folder, the server doesn't start and gives me the error:

> 'Server JBoss EAP 6.1+ Runtime Server failed to start'.

Furthermore if I add an ear in the deploy folder I get the following warning:

> 'JBAS015000: Cannot delete deployment progress marker file'.

Sometimes adding the ear's in the folder I get the errors:

> JBAS018559: Deployed "my-ear-7.5.13.ear" (runtime-name : "my-ear-7.5.13.ear")
>   17:11:18,463 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2)
>
> JBAS015877: Stopped deployment null (runtime-name: my-ejb.jar) in 32ms
>   17:11:18,511 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3)
>
> JBAS015877: Stopped deployment my-ear-7.5.13.ear (runtime-name: my-ear-7.5.13.ear) in 90ms
>   17:11:18,573 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018558: Undeployed "my-ear-7.5.13.ear"

Comment: You log don't show anything, just INFO, post log that contains WARN and ERROR lines. "Cannot delete deployment progress marker file" did you check the permission under $JBOSS_HOME ?

Comment: Furthermore console prints JBAS018559: Deployed "my-7.0.20-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name : "my-7.0.20-SNAPSHOT.war") but I see .failed file in the folder.